# Is there a way to merge/embed multiple Plotly HTML files into one page/HTML file offline?

Tags: python, html, pandas, plot, plotly

I'm trying to combine multiple charts into one HTML report to send out. The thing is I don't really think subplotting is the best idea because the charts are relatively unrelated (different X/Y axes). All I need to do is just append the charts into 1 HTML file. There is a guide that explains how to do it using plotly URLs, but I don't want to rely on an internet connection for automated reporting, and I want to be able to view these reports online

I'm trying to create an HTML report that simply just appends multiple plotly plots into one HTML file instead of having several individual HTML files. The charts aren't really related, so not interested in creating subplots. In theory it's just an HTML file, so I can just copy and paste the code a certain way and have them both show up, right?

Documentation I'm referring to: https://plot.ly/python/html-reports/

Comment: I don't see why you would avoid subplots - I'd think that would be the easiest way to get a combined HTML.

Comment: Do you want interactive D3s graphs or would it be enough with just a series of static PNG images embedded in an HTML container? The latter should be trivial to do.

Comment: Preferably interactive D3 graphs. The reason I don't want to do subplots is because there are dozens of charts that don't share X/Y axes at all, and it would be very time consuming to create multiple traces

Answer (score 0):

create a grid layout in the format you want, and then programmatically insert the html into the grid

Answer (score 0):

Here a suggestion based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/58336718/4286380

```
def plot_list(df_list):
    fig_list =[]
    from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

    # Creation des figures
    i=0
    for df in df_list:
        i+=1
        fig = go.Figure()
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=list(df.Date), y=list(df.Temp), name="Température"))

        # Add figure title
        fig.update_layout(
            title_text=f"Cas n°{i}")

        # Set x-axis title
        fig.update_xaxes(title_text="Date")

        fig_list.append(fig)

    # Création d'un seul fichier HTML
    filename=f"{os.path.join('output', 'full_list.html')}"
    dashboard = open(filename, 'w')
    dashboard.write("<html><head></head><body>" + "\n")
    include_plotlyjs = True

    for fig in fig_list:
        inner_html = fig.to_html(include_plotlyjs = include_plotlyjs).split('<body>')[1].split('</body>')[0]
        dashboard.write(inner_html)
        include_plotlyjs = False
    dashboard.write("</body></html>" + "\n")
```